# Facebook iOS Authorise and Post Without Dialog?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

Im just starting out with the Facebook SDK for iOS and checked out the documentation and other help thoroughly but can't be successful.

I have started a new view based app and authorised just as recommended in the docs. Everytime I start the app its switches to the Facebook app (which I have installed on my iPhone) and says already authorised, press okay. How can I stop it repeatedly doing this?

I also have tried posting to Facebook without a dialog. The console tells me a request is made but then a error occurs (doesn't crash but the didFailWithError tells me).

Anyway I haven't posted any of my code as it seems relatively simple so if there is someone who knows how to do this I would massively appreciate any help, and possibly even a code sample.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, is it possible to share images without dialog?? Please revert asap

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing a key point in your delegate, you have to save the session data yourself

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    // store the access token and expiration date to the user defaults
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:facebook.accessToken forKey:ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY];
    [defaults setObject:facebook.expirationDate forKey:EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

And then when you initialize facebook you would do the following

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY];
facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY];
```

And finally, if you want to post without a dialog you would do this

```
NSString *message = @"Visit my blog http://effectivemobility.blogspot.com/";
NSArray *obj = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:message, nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"message", nil];

// There are many other params you can use, check the API
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:obj forKeys:keys];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:nil];
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I added a bit about posting without a dialog to my answer

Comment: Great blog and tableview tutorial. Might actually use that. No success with no dialog posting code, it doesn't crash, but doesn't do anything. Also just to be sure Im getting the authorisation right, I copied your code but I get errors saying keys made: ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY and EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY are declared. Surely they don't need to be as we are just creating a key?

Comment: I get this error returning when trying to post: facebookErrDomain error 10000

Comment: ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY and EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY are constants. You should define them somewhere in your code. Something like
#define EXPIRATION_DATE_KEY @"ExpKey"

Comment: Last question. The fbDidLogin method, do I need to call that or does the Facebook delegate call that automatically?

Comment: The FB Delegate will call the fbDidLoginMethod when the login is succesful