# How to link Facebook to your app to allow sharing without need to login in Facebook

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I want to Link a Facebook account to my app to achieve the function like the one implemented by instagram. For example, I successfully linked my Facebook account in my app, then I want to create a post and decided to share/post it on my Facebook Wall without launching Facebook app or safari and even if I am not logged in on the device.

Does anyone here knows how to implement this? or do you know any tutorial for this. I searched on developers.facebook.com but i didn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is called SSO `Single Sign On`.Find the below link which explains the Single Sign On feature and its usage.Check [this](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/) link.

Comment: I think this is not called Single Sign On, what I really need is to never prompt for a dialog box once the user has authorized my app. Single Sign On Focuses on Signing in with facebook, or twitter, or google+ that will redirect you to one account if they are linked. Basically, storing and handling facebook tokens is what i need but I dont have an idea how to implement this the same way instagram do.

Comment: @chibimai have a look at this link https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/ . It also provides you piece of code how to persist your token.To be clear SSO is used for one time authentication only.

Comment: You can specify the permissions like `publish_stream` when you are preparing a login call so that during sharing photos Facebok SDK neve opens the facebook app or Safari asking for permission again.

Comment: this [stackoverflow question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144457/facebook-ios-authorise-and-post-without-dialog), says what I want to implement, but the problem with this is that the Facebook.h is already deprecated, any alternative way how to somewhat implement what is being done here..?